# Questions tab on mobile site doesn't sort questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, meta, mobile-web, question-lists

On the mobile site here on Meta, tapping Questions at the top shows that it is sorting by newest. I think it's quite obvious that it isn't:

[image]

Can we fix this?

Comment: Looks like your list is actually sorted by "frequent" - it doesn't do this for me on mobile though.

Comment: If you look, you see it says newest though. I've tried clearing my cache and cookies, but to no avail

Comment: Have you tried just selecting a different option in the drop-down to see if it updates?